# Get newest repos in CentOS 6

Tags: centos, yum, btrfs

I have a CentOS 6 VPS and would like to use btrfs on it. However, the version provided by `yum` is btrfs-v0.2 which is from 2013. There are newer versions like btrfs-v4.4, which I would like to use. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

btrfs has a status of a technology preview even in RedHat 7.2 - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.2_Release_Notes/technology-preview-file_systems.html

Btrfs has 2 components :

1. kernel support - https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Changelog#By_feature
2. user space utilities - https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Changelog#By_version_.28btrfs-progs.29

So it's not like you can get up to date kernel (with btrfs latest support) and user space utilities via official CentOS repos (which are public rebuild of RedHat)

You can get source code and compile user space utilities, but read what this link says in red https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Getting_started

Basically if you don't value your data - you can try to find some latest btrfs-progs rpm from Fedora or Suse or Oracle EL and see if you can install that. But since CentOS kernel is not exactly a latest thing (even though RedHat does backport code from latest kernel) and it's not clear what's the level of btrfs support in this kernel - you will be playing a lottery.